# TextView does not refresh the bitmap for getDrawingCache

Tags: android, textview, android-bitmap

I have done quite some research on this and answers did not help 100%, I did find a way to make it work but it's awful and I don't understand the behavior.

This is what I finally have:

```
private Bitmap generateBitmapFromTxt() {
        mTxtEmojicon.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTxtEmojicon.getDrawingCache());
        mTxtEmojicon.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

But the bitmap is not refreshing. I also did try:

- `invalidate()`
- `buildDrawingCache()` `destroyDrawingCache()`
- ...

I have a custom class that extends from TextView and the bitmap generated did NOT wrap words unless dynamically forcing to calculate it's size. Like this:

```
private void prepareTxtViewSize() {
        int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mEdt.getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int specHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mEdt.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        mTxt.measure(specWidth, specHeight);

        mTxt.layout(0, 0, mTxt.getMeasuredWidth(), mTxt.getMeasuredHeight());
}
```

My custom TextView class does NOT override `onDraw()`.

Now, my solution, awful solution, was to call `prepareTxtViewSize()` twice before calling `generateBitmapFromTxt()` and it works, the bitmap is refreshed and I always get the correct one.

But I am sure there is something I am missing and I am just lucky it works. So does somebody know what am I missing and/or why calling `prepareTxtViewSize()` twice actually makes the drawingCache refresh?